# (java) <name> cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables

I have tried to run the guessing game from Head First Java 2nd Edition, and I can't seem to identify what's causing the problem here.

```
class GuessGame {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;
    public void startGame() {
        p1= new Player();
        p2= new Player();
        p3= new Player();

        int guessp1=0;
        int guessp2=0;
        int guessp3=0;

        boolean p1isRight=false;
        boolean p2isRight=false;
        boolean p3isRight=false;

        int targetNumber= (int) (Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println("i'm thinking of a number between 0 and 9...");
        while(true){
            System.out.println("nr to guess is "+ targetNumber);

            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();

            guessp1=p1.number;
            System.out.println("player one guessed "+guessp1);

            guessp2=p2.number;
            System.out.println("player two guessed "+guessp2);

            guessp3=p3.number;
            System.out.println("player three guessed "+guessp3);

            if (guessp1==targetNumber){
                p1isRight=true;
            }
            if (guessp2==targetNumber){
                p2isRight=true;
            }
            if (guessp3==targetNumber){
                p3isRight=true;
            }
            if(p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                System.out.println("we have a winner!");
                System.out.println("Player one has got it right? "+p1isRight);
                System.out.println("Player two has got it right? "+p2isRight);
                System.out.println("Player three has got it right? "+p3isRight);
                System.out.println("game over bitch");
                break;
            } else { System.out.println("player will have to try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Player{
    int number=0;

    public void guess(){
        number = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println("i'm guessing " + number);
    }
}
public class GameLauncher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GuessGame = new GuessGame();
        game.startGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are missing the variable name when instancing the game:

```
public class GameLauncher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GuessGame game= new GuessGame(); //game is the variable
        game.startGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your class instance a variable name. `game` is suitable since you're already using it to call `startGame`

```
GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. Except one Typo mistake.

Object is not created for GuessGame , thats the reason you are not able to run this.

Modified:

```
   GuessGame game= new GuessGame();

    game.startGame();
```

Current:

```
   GuessGame = new GuessGame();

    game.startGame();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GameLauncher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GuessGame = new GuessGame();
        game.startGame();
    }
}
```

You haven't declared "game".  It should be:

```
GuessGame game = new GuessGame()
game.startGame()
```